# Passing instance of a class to function in c++

Tags: c++, arduino

I am programming in arduino land.  using a library AccelStepper.h with a class AccelStepper

I created an instance as follows:

```
AccelStepper panStepper(AccelStepper::DRIVER, PAN_STEP_PIN, PAN_DIR_PIN);
AccelStepper tiltStepper(AccelStepper::DRIVER, TILT_STEP_PIN, TILT_DIR_PIN);
AccelStepper dollyStepper(AccelStepper::DRIVER, DOLLY_STEP_PIN, DOLLY_DIR_PIN);
```

I want to be able to pass a reference to one of the instances and be able to change the parameters of that instance.

I am using the following to create a function to work on one of the instances as follows:

```
void CalibrateAxis(AccelStepper& stepper, int min_pin, int max_pin) {
```

this is screwing up the arduino compiler, causing it to put forward declarations for this function and others in the middle of a pragma in the main ino file as follows:

```
// RemoteXY configurate  
#pragma pack(push, 1)

//
//
void CalibrateAxis(AccelStepper& stepper, int min_pin, int max_pin);
void CalibrateAll();
void StepperSetup();
void StepperLoop();
void writeProgram();
boolean readProgram();
void stepPan(int d);
void stepTilt(int d);
void stepDolly(int d);
void Run(int s);
void dumpProgram();
void dumpTest();
void PTDSetup();
void PTDLoop();
void StateMachineLoop();

#line 38 "C:\\Users\\chris\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Arduino\\RemoteXY Stuff\\PanTiltDollyVersion2\\PanTiltDollyVersion2.ino"
uint8_t RemoteXY_CONF[] =
{ 255,16,0,27,0,89,1,10,16,0,
130,1,8,1,84,7,29,130,1,8,
44,84,17,29,130,1,46,23,46,19,
```

not sure what I am doing wrong.....

Comment: What problem are you having, exactly?  The bottom block of code is the preprocessed code, and looks like it comes from header files.

Comment: yes it is and it is resulting in the following error

compileDebugPTD.ino: 41:20: error: variable or field 'CalibrateAxis' declared void
   44,84,17,29,130,1,46,23,46,19

this is where the forwarde declarations are in the preproceesed code.

Comment: The error is pointing to the main ino file, where the  44,84,17,29,130,1,46,23,46,19 is
and the void calibrateAxis is in another ino file.

It is pointing to where the preprocessor added the forward declarations in the middle of the praga code

I am new here, any recommendations how to properly show my problem would be helpful, thanks in advance

Comment: It seems that the AccelStepper& stepper parameter is causing the problem. If i change it to an int, the preprocessor does not create that error.  It complains of a mis match further on

the preprocessor does the same thing, but the error no longer points to the main ino.
```
#pragma pack(push, 1)

//
//
void CalibrateAxis(int stepper, int min_pin, int max_pin);
void CalibrateAll();
void StepperSetup();
void StepperLoop();

#line 38 "C:\\Users\\chris\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Arduino\\compileDebugPTD\\compileDebugPTD.ino"
uint8_t RemoteXY_CONF[] =

```

Comment: How do I invoke the editor with the code button etc. when editing a reply?

Comment: Have you tried just giving it your own forward declaration in a more appropriate place and see if that stops arduino from trying to put it in for you?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to accept an answer, but  Delta_G  gave a good solution.  Thanks!

Have you tried just giving it your own forward declaration in a more appropriate place and see if that stops Arduino from trying to put it in for you? – Delta_G 1

Putting my own forward declarations fixed the issue.

fixed what the Arduino compiler could not do.